# why the first one gives me "," while the second one is without ","?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, foreach

```js
"use strict";
var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
var x = [1 , 2, 3, 4];

var final = x.map(function (value) {
    return value + "<br>" ;
});
demo.innerHTML = final;



var txt = "";
var numbers = [45, 4, 9, 16, 25];
numbers.forEach(function (value) {
  txt = txt + value + "<br>"; 
});
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = txt;
```

so what is the problem in 1st. l think there hasn't be any ",". because we say that map and foreach functions only takes value from arrays

Comment: "use script" I think you mean "use strict", and I don't get it the first final contains an array and the second contains string, you need to make a string from the first the same way you did with the second, because Array.toString() returns the values separated by commas

Comment: `map` returns an array while `forEach` creates a string with all values separated by `<br>`.

Comment: hahh yes l mean strict

Answer (score 2):

Your first example will produce an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/array). When you assign the array to `innerHTML`, it will be converted to a string, at which point [Array#toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) will be invoked. The `toString` method on `Array` prints the contents, separated by commas.

Your second example produces a string, which you then assign to `innerHTML` and no commas are inserted.

If you want to use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), then you can use something like this:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('demo');
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var final = arr.map((x) => `${x}<br/>`).join(''); // Note the join!
el.innerHTML = final;
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
body {
  perspective:800px;
  padding: 20px;
}
#demo {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 18pt;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block; 
  background: hotpink;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 50px);
  animation: go 5s ease-in-out infinite 0s;
}
@keyframes go {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotateX(25deg) rotateY(25deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotateX(-25deg) rotateY(-25deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`map()` [returns an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), not a string. So in your first example, it doesn't work because you should not assign an array to the `innerHTML` property of an element.

In order to fix your error and turn the array into a string, `toString()` is called on the array for you. This results in the commas you are seeing.

```js
var x = [1 , 2, 3, 4];

var final = x.map(function (value) {
    return value + "<br>" ;
});

console.log(final) //-> ["1<br>", "2<br>", "3<br>", "4<br>"]
console.log(final.toString()) //-> "1<br>,2<br>,3<br>,4<br>"
```

In your second example, you keep adding to a string, so it results in a string that you can set as `innerHTML` without a problem.

```js
var txt = "";

var numbers = [45, 4, 9, 16, 25];

numbers.forEach(function (value) {
  txt = txt + value + "<br>"; 
});

console.log(txt) //-> "45<br>4<br>9<br>16<br>25<br>"
```

You could also make the first version work [with a `join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to put all the items into a string.

```js
var x = [1 , 2, 3, 4];

var final = x.map(function (value) {
    return value + "<br>" ;
});

console.log(final.join('')) //-> "1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>"
```

Lastly, you can just use `join('<br>')` on the original array to do what you want in a very simple way:

```js
var x = [1 , 2, 3, 4];
var final = x.join('<br>')
console.log(final) //-> "1<br>2<br>3<br>4"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `map()` function returns a new array, so to avoid the commas you will have to `join()` the elements of the new array, like this:

```js
demo.innerHTML = final.join('');
```

You can read more in the [documentation for `map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 1):

The first one is a map.
Map lets you change the elements of an array and returns an array.

The second one is a forEach and forEach does not return.

You are seing this commas because is printing an array.

Answer (score 1):

You have commas in first one because you assign an array to `innerHTML` which will make it to string (including commas)

Look here a simple example:

```js
var html = String([1,2,3]);
console.log(html);  // IT WILL CONTAIN COMMAS
```

In second case you create an explicit string as you want (without commas)

```js
"use script";
var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
var x = [1 , 2, 3, 4];

var final = x.map(function (value) {
    return value + "<br>" ;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(final)); // <----  HERE is an array
demo.innerHTML = final;

var txt = "";
var numbers = [45, 4, 9, 16, 25];
numbers.forEach(function (value) {
  txt = txt + value + "<br>";   // << ---------- HERE is a string
});
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = txt;
```

```html
  <div id="demo"></div>
  <hr>
  <div id="demo2"> </div>
```

If you want to have the same you can use `join` to create a string from array (without commas) like this:

```js
"use script";
var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
var x = [1 , 2, 3, 4];

var final = x.map(function (value) {
    return value + "<br>" ;
});
demo.innerHTML = final.join('');

var txt = "";
var numbers = [45, 4, 9, 16, 25];
numbers.forEach(function (value) {
  txt = txt + value + "<br>"; 
});
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = txt;
```

```html
  <div id="demo"></div>
  <hr>
  <div id="demo2"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have done that as simple as this

```js
"use strict";
var demo1 = document.getElementById("demo1"),
  demo2 = document.getElementById("demo2"),
  x = [1, 2, 3, 4],
  numbers = [45, 4, 9, 16, 25];

demo1.innerHTML = x.join("<br>");
demo2.innerHTML = numbers.join("<br>");
```

```html
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
```